# Reducing the amount of time that it takes to do date calculations

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I am running the following code in cellForRow that does an on-the-fly date calculation. After seeing some stuttering whilst scrolling, I ran a Time Profiler while replicating the stuttering and determined that this bit of my code is the issue. As far as I am aware, this is the best way to accomplish getting a double for difference in number of days and then converting to number of years? Any suggestions on how to reduce the amount of time this takes to hopefully improve scrolling?

[image]

Comment: If your values are constant maybe you can store the calculated values in a model or something.

Comment: Your biggest mistake here is storing dates in your models as strings, and using NSArray/NSDictionary. Don't do that. Use Swift's native types (`Array<Element>`, `Dictionary<Key, Value>`), and store the dates properly (as `Date`s) so that you're not constantly re-parsing the same things over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Provide default value and then use a completion handler to detect when the calculation is finished. then use reload rows at indexpath. That will let the user scroll and calculate the value in the background. And once the value is calculated, it will reload the cell to show the final value.

Answer (score 0):

Date Formatters are always a heavy task to perform. If we are performing inside the table view cell then we will face scrolling issue with the table view. Approach for better performances using table view cell + Date formatters is to provide final data values to table view cell subview components. Data decoration should be done prior to assigning values to the table view cell.

Instead of using Dictionary use struct to provide data to cell. While initializing model classes all date formatters work should be done.

Now model class array will be passed to table view to render table.